# How to set additional properties during RemoveExistingProducts

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I am using the *recommended* way to upgrade (Use **Upgrade** and **UpgradeVersion** to detect the old version of the product and use **RemoveExistingProducts** after **InstallInitialize**

The thing is, during uninstall of the existing product, I need to pass additional properties to installer for preserving existing database. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All a product being removed via **RemoveExistingProducts** receives is a single extra property **UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE**. This property is set to match the **ProductCode** of the installer which is removing this other product. If you had a condition against this in the installer being removed, it can act accordingly. If not, you will need to make your UpgradeVersion *OnlyDetect* and block until it's gone, invoke its removal manually, or similar workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uninstalling from the command line, you can use

```
msiexec /x c:\Example.msi PROPERTY=VALUE
```

to initialise your properties.

Alternatively, you can store the properties in the registry and use something like :

```
<Property Id="PROPNAME">
  <RegistrySearch Id="PropNameRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyProduct\MyKey\PropValue" Name="MyPropName" />
</Property>
```

to retrieve them.

Comment: See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern for details about using the registry for property persistence.